# msbuild copies nuget package lib from different location then packages\*package_name*?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

I have C# application (.NET Framework 4.6.2) with WebApi projects which references **System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation (v4.3.0)** library through nuget package. See
[Nuget package reference screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guRE9.png) Package was auto-installed as a dependency of 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.2.2.0, Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.2.1.0'

This application was working fine (**Builds from my localhost are ok**) until I tried to do automatic builds from my teamcity server (**different machine**). For some reason builds of my app which are provided by teamcity will not start. I get error [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.2.0...'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXByE.png)

So I started to investigate and I found out this:

- Builds from my localhost (bin/debug) contains lib System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll (File version=**4.6.26011.1**, Date modified=10.8.2021) *--this build works fine*
- Teamcity build contains lib System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll (File version=**4.6.24705.1**, Date modified=11.5.2016) *--this build is not working*
- Nuget package which was downloaded (..\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0) on both machines (localhost and teamcity server) contains System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll (File version=**4.6.24705.1**, Date modified=11.5.2016)

And now I am stuck and literally dont know how to investigate it further. Questions I am asking myself:

1. How is it possible that my localhost builds contains this reference lib with file version **4.6.26011.1** when in my \packages\ folder this .dll contains file version **4.6.24705.1**? Does msbuild maybe take this reference from different location? But from where? I swear I searched my computer and I did not found this library in version **4.6.26011.1** (which is apparently copied to bin/debug by msbuild).
2. Is there a way to monitor msbuild process and see from where it copies this .dll reference to my bin/debug/ folder on my localhost machine?
3. How to fix my references so the app runs fine?

---

*21.6.2022 Edit:*

Thanks to @mu88 comment I have managed to find out that this library is copied from this location: *"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2021.2.2\tools\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net462\lib\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll"* to my bin\debug. I have zero ideas why msbuild is using this path for this lib. (This is only library which is copied from this path)
--Additional info: I am using some AspNetCore references (e.g Kestrel, ..) so I am targeting .Net Standard 2.0. Could this relate? I am asking because my investigation lead to [this issue: ms-build-extensions-file-corrupt-my-bin-web-api-folder](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/51dc828b-43ca-4177-b68e-7a6a9cf81db5/ms-build-extensions-file-corrupt-my-bin-web-api-folder?forum=msbuild). In this issue I have found other links to people having similiar problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875551/net-framework-4-6-1-application-has-errors-referencing-net-standard-1-4-class). I just dont understand the solution there :(

Comment: I assume on your local machine there is a .NET SDK installed which is missing on TeamCity - hence the newer version of `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll`. You can increase MSBuild's verbosity with `-verbosity:diag`

Comment: @mu88 thanks for your advice. Thanks to -verbosity:diag option I was able to discover that **System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll** (!only this library!) is copied from "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2021.2.2\tools\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net462\lib\" on my localhost. I have no idea what Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions is and why msbuild uses this location to "override" my reference. Any ideas?
Additional info: I am using some AspNetCore references (e.g Kestrel, ..) so I am targeting .Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: At least we can explain the difference - well done! Could you try to build with VS on your machine? Will it also pick up the assembly from the JetBrains folder?

Comment: @mu88 Hey, I just installed VisualStudio 2022 (17.2.5) and I builded my solution. Result is the same as with JB Rider but this time it takes package from *"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net462\lib\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll"*. So the .dll is once again overriden by Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions. I really want to understand why so I created [new stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72742397/what-is-microsoft-net-build-extensions-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @mu88 So I managed to solve my problem. I had to install **.NET SDK** to **Visual Studio Build Tools 2019** via Visual Studio Installer. Which done "some" magic and it created *MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\* folder to my msbuild and now during the build process some System libraries are "overidden" and copied from this new location. So even if I use nuget to download System lib it is actualy useless and this package is not used during the build. 
I did not manage to find any more info why is it so :( would be nice if someone explained this to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to solve my problem. I had to install **.NET SDK** to **Visual Studio Build Tools 2019** via **Visual Studio Installer**. Which done "some" magic and it created *MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions* folder to my msbuild and now during the build process some System libraries are "overidden" and copied from this new location.
[image: Screenshot]

So even if I use nuget to download System lib then this package is not used during the build.

I did not manage to find any more info about the build process :( It would be nice if someone could explain this to me. I created a separate question for this here: [What is Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72742397/what-is-microsoft-net-build-extensions-and-how-does-it-work).